# using one to many over many to many sql

Tags: sql

I'm designing a database model where there are agents that can have customers.
From a best practice standpoint, I'd like to know what is best relationship to use.

The thing is, a customer could be working with multiple agents. If we want to consider that the customer should be treated as if they are being worked from a different angle, is it best practice to design the model as a one to many relationship instead of a many to many?

In otherwords, if Agent A and Agent B are working with John Doe, should we treate John Doe as separate entities for each agent, even though the record of John Doe may be the same (think like contact details).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you simply want a junction/association table with columns such as:

- CustomerId
- AgentId

You may also want dates, descriptions and other information describing the relationship being worked on.

Comment: this may be the same, but a linking table? Agent on left, table in the middle with agent_id and customer_id, and customer table on the right (thinking of a graphic layout of the tables)

Comment: @dataviews . . . You just might want to include other information on each row, apart from the two foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to have agent_customer table? Which has the auto increment ID as PK, agentID and customerID so one agent can have multiple customers and a customer can have multiple agents. Make sure to make agentID and customerID unique to avoid redundancy.